# primary column width in new splitviewcontroller (iOS 14)

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, sidebar

How does one change the width of the primary column in new splitviewcontroller (iOS 14)? I'm using preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.5 and it doesn't have any effect. My svc has style = doubleColumn and my primary (sidebar) has appearance = .sideBar.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, you have to also supply a `maximumPrimaryColumnWidth` as well. So something like:

```
splitVC.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.3
splitVC.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 0.3 * UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
```

At least, that's what worked for me with doubleColumn and splitBehavior `.tile`

Comment: You're an absolute lifesaver! This should be granted as accepted solution.